# Is this an efficient way of mounting a file-system via SSH (SSHFS)?

Tags: python, linux

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 

# Description: Python script that will mount FTP-Server via SSHFS protocol 
import sys
import os
import subprocess

def mount():
#Function for mounting the networked drive
    if os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/MEDIA/'):
        print('Network drive is mounted')
        un = input("To unmount type U/u \n")
        if un == "u" or un == "U":
            subprocess.call(['sudo fusermount -u /home/user/MNT/'], shell=True)  
        else:
            pass 
        exit(0) 
    if not os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/MEDIA/'):
        IP = input("Type I/i for local connection, E/e for external\n")
        if IP == "i" or IP == "I":
            subprocess.call(['sudo sshfs -o idmap=user -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other -o default_permissions -p 100 user@10.0.0.100:/media/Hitachi/ /home/user/MNT'], shell=True)
        if IP == "e" or IP == "E":
            subprocess.call(['sudo sshfs -o idmap=user -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other -o default_permissions -p 100 user@xxxxxxxx.com/media/Hitachi/ /home/user/MNT'], shell=True) 
        elif IP == "": #returns if null value 
            return mount()


def makedir():
#Function to check and see if directory is created and if not create it
    if not os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/'):
        subprocess.call(['sudo mkdir /home/user/MNT/'], shell=True)
    if os.path.isdir('/home/user/MNT/'):
        mount() 






makedir()
```

EDITED:

```
def sshfs():
#function to mount network drive
    while True:
        user = input("Type 'i' for internal, 'e' for external connection\n")
        fs = File_System.get(user.lower()) #Get value from the dict called File_System
        if fs is None:
            print("Invalid option, enter either 'i' for internal or 'e' for external\n")
        else:
            subprocess.call(["sudo sshfs -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o idmap=user -o default_permissions -o allow_other -p 100 %s %s" % (fs, Local_Mount)], shell=True)
            exit(0)
```

Comment: Please provide some more context. Looking at the code tells us one what you are actually doing, but having a general description of what you want to do may give some opportunity to provide alternative suggestions too.

Comment: Just trying to make a script to use with all my linux machines to mount to a centralized server

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency is just not an issue in this kind of task.  As "glue" code, it's not computationally intensive.  There are, however, some maintainability issues.

- In `mount()`, the basic outline is:

  ```
  def mount():
      if os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/MEDIA/'):
          ...
          exit(0) 
      if not os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/MEDIA/'):
          ...
  ```

  … which should be expressed as:

  ```
  def mount_or_unmount():
      if os.path.exists('/home/user/MNT/MEDIA/'):
          ...
      else:
          ...
  ```
- Using recursion for error handling is weird.  That would normally be handled using a while-loop.  It's also slightly odd that the empty string triggers a retry, but any other invalid input would exit the script.
- The two `sudo sshfs` commands differ only slightly.  Your code should be structured accordingly.

  ```
  REMOTE_FS = {
      'i': 'user@10.0.0.100:/media/Hitachi/',
      'e': 'user@xxxxxxxx.com/media/Hitachi/',
  }

  ...
  while True:
      ip = input("Type I/i for local connection, E/e for external\n")
      fs = REMOTE_FS.get(ip.lower())
      if fs is None:    # Input was not 'i' or 'e'
          continue
      subprocess.call(['sudo sshfs -o idmap=user -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other -o default_permissions -p 100 %s /home/user/MNT' % (fs)], shell=True)
      break
  ```

Comment: Awesome, I reedited my code and I learned a lot, especially with reducing 'glue' code. However I have one question and I need it dumbed down

    while True:
Till what is true? Why/How does the loop end?

Comment: Yikes! Forgot a very important `break`. Good catch!

Comment: I did it slightly different. I'm still confused as to why the loop breaks even without the break statement?:

Comment: @Joe `exit(0)` in your case is the equivalent of `break`